What is the Optimal Approach to Scaling Listeners in the Backend
I want to have lots of listeners in my express.js backend, is there a standard way to scale this without it slowing down the rest of the server?
Using a different server for listening would be ok too but wondering what the industry standard is for something like this
I haven't tried anything yet, I'm just thinking of an approach and would appreciate any ideas.
